# Just want to know whether the casts in the example are redundant

Tags: c

Just want to know whether the casts in the example below are redundant.

uint16_t basic_units = 4587U;

uint8_t int_val =  (uint8_t) (((uint16_t ) (basic_units * 5U)) / 1000U);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `uint8_t` cast is redundant. The `uint16_t` cast may have the (un)intended consequence of truncating an intermediate value in the calculation if `basic_units * 5U` would overflow a normal `uint16_t` before being divided by 1000.

Comment: +1, assuming `unsigned int` is bigger than 16 bits, and the question isn't supposed to only be about the given value `4587`.

Comment: basic_units * 5U will never overflow uint16_t. So, I think I can safely remove both the uint8_t and uint16_t casts. Please advise.

Comment: @Ammamon: if you're willing to assume that it'll never overflow then remove the cast. It hints at the possibility of something that will never happen, and hence just slows down the reader. If `basic_units` might change in future then choose whichever would produces the correct result, were that to happen. Also note that assuming no wraparound, you can just divide by 200, so the *multiplication* is redundant too in that case ;-)

Comment: Thank you Steve. You are right. I can as well divide by 200. But to make the implementation of domain logic clear, I want to retain 5U and 1000U as such. (Later, I will change these to defined constants). Thank you again for patiently answering to this trivial question.

Answer (score 0):

I think **(uint16_t)** in

> (uint8_t) (((uint16_t ) (basic_units *
>   5U)) / 1000U)

is redundant.;

Simply because

> The Uint16_t is a synonym for
>   "unsigned short"

and

> uint8_t is just a typedef for unsigned
>   char

Comment: If `basic_units` is equal to 20000, and `unsigned int` is bigger than 16 bits, then it alters the result, hence not redundant. It might be wrong, depending which result you wanted. But in the example, `basic_units` is only 4587, I'm not sure whether the question is only about that one value.

Comment: The maximum possible basic_units is 7000 and I am using MSP430.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate on the redundancy part. The thing that you are trying to do is an insecure practice and highly inadvisable as you are going for a shortening conversion(converting 16 bits to 8 bits).

P.S
it is just enough if you write uint8_t int_val = (uint8_t) ((basic_units * 5U)/ 1000U);

Comment: Thank you code rider. I am sure that the right side of the expression will always be less than 255. I have now added an assert as follows. uint16_t val = ((basic_units * 5U)/ 1000U); assert (val <= 255); int_val = val;